# ¿Cómo puedo comunicar dos controladores en Angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, servicio, component

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es pasar como parametro en una función un dato que tiene otro componente, el otro componente es una lista y lo que quiero obtener es el id_transacion de la transacción, porque en la otra pantalla voy a mostrar lo destalles de esa transaccion, les pongo mi código, espero a haberme dado a entender, tampoco puedo usar localstorage.

```html
<tr *ngFor="let transaction of reportList | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 12, currentPage: p }">
   <td> <input type="checkbox" name="" value=""> </td>
   <td>{{transaction.id_transaccion}}</td>
   <td>{{transaction.id_sucursal}}</td>
   <td>{{transaction.cuenta}}</td>
   <td>{{transaction.puntos}}</td>
   <td>{{transaction.referencia}}</td>
   <td>{{transaction.total}}</td>
   <td>{{transaction.fecha}}</td>
   <td class="button"><a class="btn backGreenF" routerLink="transaction-data">Ver</a></td>
  </tr>
```

Y este es donde quiero poner los datos, que vienen de otro endpoint pero necesito como parametro el id_transaction de arriba

```html
<div class="data-details-concept">
      <p>ID:</p>
      <p>Sucursal:</p>
      <p>Usuario Operador:</p>
      <p>Cuenta:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="data-details-concept">
      <p class="bold">{{id}}</p>
      <p class="bold">{{transactionData.Sucursal}}</p>
      <p class="bold">{{transactionData.Usuario}}</p>
      <p class="bold">{{transactionData.Usuario}}</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Lo que podrías hacer es usar un behaviorSubject para guardar el valor seleccionado y en el componente de abajo solo consultas el valor que tiene, y haces tu proceso.

Comment: son ambos componentes padre e hijo? hay mucha informacion sobre eso usando input o output, en caso contrario se puede emitir un evento al que te suscribas pero es mejor usar un servicio en comun entre los dos componentes.